# Google Analytics GIF request not sent

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I'm having some troubles setting up Google Analytics. I downloaded the Google Analytics Debugging extension for Chrome and if I take a look at the console, the __utm.gif request is never sent. I triple-checked my code, and everything is fine. The debugging version of ga.js is downloaded properly. In fact, I have the exact same problem as [this guy that never got an answer](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/f6eh0VpdgJw)...

For the sake of it, here is my tracking code (with `UA-########-#` properly replaced in my original code, of course)

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-#']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Everything is set up properly, and here is what I get in the console output :

```
_gaq.push processing : "[_setAccount, UA-########-#]"
_gaq.push processing : "[_trackPageview]"
Track Pageview
```

And then nothing else. I tried with a colleague's personal website that I know has Google Analytics installed and I can see the request for the .gif file.

Anyone ever had this problem ?

Comment: Could you post some of your script where you initialize and call the GA code?

Comment: @shanabus: The script is an exact copy paste from Google Analytics site. (exept for the UA-### of course)

Comment: do you have any other code thats writing to the console such as a js function or something?  What about another plugin that could be interfering?

Comment: thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you testing your site on localhost or an intranet? If so, you may need to add

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
```

before `_trackPageview`

See [Google Analytics on Intranets and Development Servers](http://analyticsimpact.com/2011/01/20/google-analytics-on-intranets-and-development-servers-fqdn/) for more info...

> If you’re using Google Analytics on a site with a URL like
>   http://intranet/ or something like http://mydevserver:12345 it won’t
>   work.
>
> Specifically, the Google Analytics JS code will not send the tracking
>   hit (__utm.gif) to the GA servers.
>
> I don’t really know the specifics, but I’m guessing that the domain
>   hashing code looks for at least one period in the hostname and won’t
>   work if it doesn’t find one.

Comment: Thank you!!! Indeed I was testing on localhost. I did not think it made any difference. Now it works !

Comment: Does it matter if I leave that piece of code there when the site goes to production ? Is there an impact on the statistics ?

Comment: If all the pages on your site are in one domain or sub-domain, then there's no problem leaving it in.

Comment: Without this answer I would have been debugging pointlessly for probably another 2 days

Comment: +1 it also happens when the domain is wrong i.e. as when changing domains and missed changing that

Comment: Also happens for _trackEvent when the 'label' is not a string (console reports Track Event but doesn't report beacon sent).

Comment: Fixed my issue, too. Thought I was going crazy. Thank you!

Comment: I don't remember this being an issue with the previous synchronous syntax using ga('send', 'pageview'). I never suspected this would be a localhost problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am suffer the same issue in chrome extension development env, finnally, save save my life!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not receiving the `Tracking beacon sent!` message then it could be one of the following:

- A problem with Cookie settings in your browser (however unlikely in your case)
- An issue with your proxy/firewall (can you check fiddler or your Network tab and see if any of your resources were 404'd?)
- A javascript error (anything else at all in your console?)

Hope this helps you debug your situation. I'll update this answer if you provide any more information.

**UPDATE**

It may help to make sure that the issue is with the Chrome Analytics debugger plugin versus your analytics setup.  To do this, open something like Fiddler or in Chrome under Resources - Frames - (page) - Images.  You should see the request for __utm.gif there.  If you do not, its an issue with your Analytics setup.  If you do, its just an issue with the Chrome Analytics debugger.

To answer your question though, I've only seen something similar happen one other time and that was on a site with Google Ads.  I received an **Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL...** error.

Comment: This is the only output I get in the console. I already checked for 404'd resources and nothing there. Cookies are enabled, I am not behind a proxy. I disabled my firewall and it did not help.