# Test Google Analytics from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, seo, google-analytics

I've seen this: [Can you test google analytics on a localhost address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address) and [Getting Google Analytics to see a test server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317190/getting-google-analytics-to-see-a-test-server) followed what was suggested, but nothing works.

What I did:

- Edited my hosts file to have several additional domains.
- Created virtual hosts on my local Apache httpd server.
- Created an account in Google Analytics, created several "properties" (as in websites that belong to me) in that account.
- Wrote a testing HTML page that would report a page view to the Google Analytic service.

All listings are shown below:

`c:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   ad-test             # for testing ad banners
127.0.0.1   testing.foo.tv      # for testing ad banners
127.0.0.1   testing.foo-sdk.tv  # for testing ad banners
```

The relevant part of `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ad-test
DocumentRoot D:/cygwin/home/wvxvw/projects/AdModule
   <Directory "D:/cygwin/home/wvxvw/projects/AdModule">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*(looks the same for all other hosts)*

The `AdModule` directory has the following `index.html` file:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script></body></html>
```

*(There is also a variation that uses newer API, but I'm not posting it for shortness)*

The `document.domain` property in the above HTML page is set to the domain I specified in the Google Analytics account settings.

When I look at the requests sent to Google Analytics service, I can see the JavaScript being loaded and then the gif image, too. I can call other API functions w/o errors, but nothing gets displayed in the dashboard.

**UPDATE**

I was back on my PC in two days and here's what I found on the Google Analytics page:

[image]

Problem solved...

Comment: how long are you waiting to see the data? Data takes upwards of 24 hours to show up in GA

Comment: Wait a little bit. GA is not realtime.

Comment: @wvxvw that is just a tool for GA to check if there is page code. It is not the same thing as receiving data and making it available in the reports.

Comment: I have the same problem. What happened ? did the data show up ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Real time" -> Overview from left navigations to see live data