# Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, tracking

I am trying to implement the google event tracking api into a html5 player, but for some reason it doesn't want to work.. Here is what i am doing:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-myid-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com//u/ga_debug.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();


    if (typeof _gaq != undefined){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'krusty-player', eventName, 'demo', 1]);
    }
```

i copied the code from the google documentation page, so i guess it has to be right. From the Developer Console i don't see any HTTP request happening when the code runs, but when i do :

```
console.log(_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'krusty-player', eventName]));
```

i get a counter that goes up +1 for every time this part is called. No errors here..

i also tried using:

```
_trackEvent('krusty-player', eventName);
```

This returns error "_trackEvent is not defined"

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It looks fine. Does the `_trackPageview` occurs correctly?

Comment: @MathieuImbert no.. i don't see a request for this one as well..

Comment: What *request* are you looking for? It should be an image file called `__utm.gif`

Comment: well i am clearing the console and no new request come in when i trigger the event. Either way i was searching for something like what is posted here: http://pranshuarya.com/jaal/Development/how-to-check-google-analytics-event-tracking.html

Comment: It is very hard to debug with no access to the code. Is your website public? Can we see it?

Comment: nope, afraid not:/ what bugs me the most is that _trackEvent() says is not defined..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15959/discussion-between-mathieu-imbert-and-tk66)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you testing on localhost or an intranet? See [Google Analytics GIF request not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738815/google-analytics-gif-request-not-sent/9741228#9741228) for details.
TLDR: the tracking GIF request doesn't get made for localhost servers by default.

Regarding `_trackEvent is not defined`: _trackEvent() isn't a stand alone function and needs to be called via _gaq.push

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action])
```

or via a pageTracker object (old style, non-async analytics)

```
pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action)
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. 

@tk66: I feel this should be accepted as an answer...

Comment: Make sure you have the asynchronous Tracking code installed... https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `_gaq.push` action on an event.

Like :

```
<span onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', EVENT_NAME, EVENT_ACTION, EVENT_DESCRIPTION]);">Click me</span>
```

And rename the caps names with plain / dynamic generated text and it should work.

Comment: then just put `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', EVENT_NAME, EVENT_ACTION, EVENT_DESCRIPTION]);` on the keyboard event ( `$('#target').keydown(function() {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', EVENT_NAME, EVENT_ACTION, EVENT_DESCRIPTION]);
});` and eventually if you want filter the keyboard event you desire - http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: it is a big project and the structure for keyboard events is already there.. so i can't change the way it is.. But shouldn't it work the same way in javascript?

Comment: Yes, it should. I have that exact same code in all the project and they work. Sorry I cannot be of more assistance.